# login with any password

Tags: linux, passwords, pam

I am having a strange problem in the sense that one of the users in my server is able to login with any password whose first eight characters same as the actual password of the user. For example, if the actual password of a user is `abcdefgh` then login with `abcdefgh` as the password, as well as `abcdefgh2002` or `abcdefghijkl` succeeds, but not with `2001abcdefgh`. I am using PAM with shadow file. The user in concern has a hash of his password in /etc/shadow file, but it does not have any salt as far as i can see.

I tried it with my own account, but did not result in successful login.

Comment: What encryption method are you using?

Comment: As TomH points out, it is crypt(3)

Comment: But there are other accounts that have hash in the form of `$id$salt$encrypted` and are random. My guess is password set from `webmin` and `passwd` have `$id$salt$encrypted` format, while password changed from Horde's interface to password has `crypt` format.

Answer (score 3):

That user has an ancient `crypt` hash. It is is salted, but it only uses the first eight characters of the password.

You can verify this by looking at the hash in `/etc/shadow` and if it doesn't start with a `$n$` marker to indicate the hash method then it is using the original unix `crypt` hash which only uses the first eight characters. See `crypt(3)` for more information.

If he changes the password, even to the same thing, it will be updated to use whatever hash is set as the default on your system, which is usually something more modern and secure like `SHA512`.

Incidentally, in those old style hashes the salt is just the first two characters of the hash which is why you thought there wasn't one. Newer hashes look like `$id$salt$encrypted` which is probably what you are used to to but old ones are just thirteen characters with the first two being the salt.

Comment: so, basically only the first eight characters of the password is significant, if crypt hash is used?

Comment: Yes, to quote `crypt(3)` "By taking the lowest 7 bits of each of the first eight characters of the key, a 56-bit key is obtained...

Comment: how can I ensure that salted hash is used? I believe salted hash does support longer password. I think the utility used to change password is poppassd, at least it is changed from Horde email client, not passwd tool

Comment: the last paragraph now makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Well if it goes through `pam` then the hash algorithm can be specified as an argument to the `pam_unix.so` module, but I would expect any modern distro to do that unless `poppasswd` is using a completely custom pam stack. Other tools are typically controlled by `/etc/login.defs`.

Comment: my system is on CentOS 5 and uses standard distribution of `poppassws`. I am also looking at `/etc/login.defs`, particularly the last line `MD5_CRYPT_ENAB yes`. Any pointers to howto's would be highly appreciated.

Comment: man pages for `login.defs` point me towards pam configuration files. may be i should have a look around that avenue

Comment: finally had some time to work with `/etc/pam.d/popasswd`. Got it to work with MD5. Thanks a lot.